# JavaFX/FXML: initialize() in controller class is never called

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Trying to acquaint myself with JavaFX I ran into the following problem:

I used Scene Builder to generate an FXML with my controller class specified as `fx:controller="application.MainController"` and I used the sample code generated by Scene Builder to create the MainController class in the according package.
Now although I'm not seeing any error messages apparently the `initialize()` method is never called after loading the FXML (tried Breakpoints and `System.out.println`). What am I missing?

Comment: Argh, never mind. I've been looking for a solution for over an hour, but it turns out that apparently Eclipse or the VM used a cached version of my FXML which didn't have the controller class defined in it yet...
Restarting Eclipse fixed it. Is there a simpler way than restarting? Hitting refresh in the package explorer didn't help. Do I have to open a new thread for that question?

Comment: When using eclipse, you always have to `clean your project` whenever you change the `FXML` or another file (such as a `css`).

Comment: Use the [e(fx)clipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse) plugin, which allows you to edit css and fxml files (or open SceneBuilder) from within the project. I've never needed to clean the project when changing these files.

Comment: Also, if you want further help, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).